# How to add time series data stored in a csv column to rdf graph

Tags: time-series, rdf, ontology, json-ld

I have a set of multiple files that store time series data.
The time series data is stored as a CSV file with multiple large columns.
E.g.:

| Time | Force |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.1 |
| 2 | 0.2 |
| 3 | 0.2 |
| 4 | 0.3 |
| ... | ... |

I would like to make this data accessible using RDF without conversion of the actual data into RDF. The columns in the file should be related to ontology individuals.
I know I can create a json-ld file that stores the meta information of the file. I read that this file is usually stored together with the csv file as "-metadata.json" file.

I made a minimal example for my table:

```
{
   "@context":[
      "http://www.w3.org/ns/csvw"
   ],
   "url":"PATH-TO-URL",
   "dialect":{
      "delimiter":"\t",
      "skipRows":4,
      "headerRowCount":2,
      "encoding":"ISO-8859-1"
   },
   "tableSchema":{
      "columns":[
         {
            "titles":"Time",
            "@id":"Time",
            "@type":"Column"
         },
         {
            "titles":"Force",
            "@id":"Force",
            "@type":"Column"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Now I also have an ontology, with individuals representing time and force of a specific experiment (F1 and T1). This ontology is stored in a tripplestore.
E.g.:

```
@prefix : <http://www.semanticweb.org/example#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@base <http://www.semanticweb.org/example> .

<http://www.semanticweb.org/example> rdf:type owl:Ontology .

#################################################################
#    Object Properties
#################################################################

###  http://www.semanticweb.org/example#hasDataReference
:hasDataReference rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty .


#################################################################
#    Classes
#################################################################

###  http://www.semanticweb.org/example#Force
:Force rdf:type owl:Class .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/example#Time
:Time rdf:type owl:Class .


#################################################################
#    Individuals
#################################################################

###  http://www.semanticweb.org/example#F1
:F1 rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
             :Force .


###  http://www.semanticweb.org/example#T1
:T1 rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual ,
             :Time .
```

I would like to relate these individuals to the columns stored in the "-metadata.json" file. So that the user can locate the specific column by following the graph from the individuals.

What would be the correct way to link the individuals with the column location ? Do I need to convert the json-ld to ttl, add it to the tripplestore and then add a relation to the column, e.g. using my "hasDataReference" relation?

I think the file itself could be made accessible using an ontology like dcat.

In general, I am looking for the recommended way to make csv data (e.g. the columns and rows) available via an ontology-based graph.

I do not want to load the entire column in the tripplestore only the location of the column in the file, so that the user can extract the column if needed.

Comment: A JSON-LD file is just an encoding for an RDF graph. Regarding how to model your problem in RDF, it depends on what you want to say about the data. I understand that you do not want to express in RDF what's inside the table ("without conversion of the actual data into RDF") so maybe you just want that an entity relate to the URL of the file? It is not very clear what you're after exactly.

Comment: @AntoineZimmermann I added some more details. I do want to relate the column location and the file.